# Rails Memoization on a has many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to cache instance variable through memoization on a SQL query that includes has_many associations?  In the two example methods below some_instance method will cache as expected, but the some_other_instance will cache Artist but not the song association which results in a SQL query each time the method is run.

It seems when the method returns "ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy" or "ActiveRecord::Relation" it won't cache entirely.

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :artist_songs
    has_many :songs, through: :artist_songs

    def self.some_instance
        @some_instance ||= find(10)
    end

    def self.some_other_instance
        @some_other_instance ||= find(10).songs
    end
end
```

Comment: Saying "works fine on the first" do you really mean that it doesn't perform select for `songs` table with `select * from songs ...` SQL query? "the second will still perform SQL query" - which query exactly are you talking about? If you are annoyed with query that finds an `Artist` in the second method, then just use the first method that memoizes it: `@some_other_instance ||= some_instance.songs`.

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity.  The "some_instance" method caches variable and don't perform more SQL queries when running the method again.  The "some_other_instance" method caches Artist but doesn't cache the song association so when running the method again I see SQL queries for the song collection.

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion of rewriting "some_other_instance" method but getting same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Can you show the output you have for both calls of `some_other_instance` method?

Answer (score 0):

The `some_instance` method caches the result of the `find(10)` method which executes DB query and returns a record.

But the `some_other_instance` method caches a relation object rather than the result of DB query. Actually if you run in rails console like `Artist.some_other_instance;` (**note ; at the end**) there won't be any DB query because you don't use the result of the query. But when you just run `Artist.some_other_instance` there will be the query because the result is used to be printed.

So to really cache `some_other_instance` method you need to add like `to_a` for example:

`def self.some_other_instance
  @some_other_instance ||= find(10).songs.to_a
end`

But in this case this method won't be "chainable".

Comment: to_a did what I was hoping for, thanks.    Unless someone has a way of doing this without having to turn into array this seem like the best option.

Comment: Actually it's impossible to cache a relation result without getting it's DB query via `to_a` or something else. Because a relation is just a wrapper for SQL query and when you chain some relations the result SQL query changes as well. Therefore is't logical.

Comment: Copy. That way to go then. I've added a follow up question above regarding performance on to_a in itself.

Answer (score 0):

The to_a is providing the solution for caching the relations.

In the log below SQL queries takes 1883.4ms & building views 623.4ms.  The total time is 15053ms which means adding to_a on the objects is taking 12546.2ms.  If I switch off to_a the total time comes down to just about 2000ms.

Is this normal that it would take that long to build the objects?

```
Started GET "/build" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-14 16:35:30 -0700
Processing by ArtistsController#build as HTML
  Artist Load (208.4ms)  SELECT `artists`.`id`, `artists`.`name`, `artists`.`uri`, `artists`.`artwork_url`, updates.popularity, updates.created_at AS pop_created_at, reachupdates.reach, reachupdates.created_at AS reach_created_at FROM `artists` INNER JOIN `updates` ON `updates`.`artist_id` = `artists`.`id` INNER JOIN `reachupdates` ON `reachupdates`.`artist_id` = `artists`.`id` WHERE `artists`.`id` = 1
  Song Load (510.5ms)  SELECT songs.*, songupdates.* FROM `songs` INNER JOIN `artist_songs` ON `artist_songs`.`song_id` = `songs`.`id` INNER JOIN `artists` ON `artists`.`id` = `artist_songs`.`artist_id` INNER JOIN `songupdates` ON `songupdates`.`song_id` = `songs`.`id` WHERE `artists`.`id` = 1
  Playlist Load (1089.2ms)  SELECT playlists.*, playlistupdates.* FROM `playlists` INNER JOIN `playlist_songs` ON `playlist_songs`.`playlist_id` = `playlists`.`id` INNER JOIN `songs` ON `songs`.`id` = `playlist_songs`.`song_id` INNER JOIN `playlistupdates` ON `playlistupdates`.`playlist_id` = `playlists`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `artist_songs` ON `artist_songs`.`song_id` = `songs`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `artists` ON `artists`.`id` = `artist_songs`.`artist_id` WHERE `artists`.`id` = 1 AND `playlists`.`relevant` = 1 AND (playlistupdates.id IN (SELECT MAX(playlistupdates.id) AS id FROM playlistupdates GROUP BY playlistupdates.playlist_id)) ORDER BY `playlistupdates`.`followers` DESC
  Rendering artists/build.html.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered artists/build.html.haml within layouts/application (15.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.haml (45.8ms)
  Rendered svg/_settings.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered svg/_search.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header_new.html.haml (73.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_autocomplete-box.html.haml (14.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 15053ms (Views: 623.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1883.4ms)
```

Comment: Time aspect is totally different question. Because we don't know how big the tables are, how many data you need for this particular page, etc. It can take a long time for example because you retrieve a lot of records from DB and then Ruby tries to build AR instances in memory, it might you don't even need that. In other words, it's quite different question.